# How to sort references in order using IEEE trans bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

I am working on an IEEE transaction template on Overleaf. I have a separate .bib file I am citing in the main .tex file using these tags:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,biblio_traps_dynamics}
```

The problem is, that in the bibliography section the references are not listed in order: after 1-8 instead of no 9 its 13.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? As far as I can see there is only one valid bib file, since `IEEEabrv.bib` is actually part of the LaTeX distribution.

Comment: the bib file is biblio_traps_dynamics.bib i dont know why we need to wrote IEEEabrv here in tag \bibliography{IEEEabrv,biblio_traps_dynamics}

Comment: In [`IEEEabrv.bib`](http://tug.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEabrv.bib), there are `@STRING` defined, so for example when you use `journal = IEEE_J_IT` in the bib file, it will print out *IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory*. Similarly, there is `IEEEfull.bib`. In IEEE publications, we normally use the abrv form. But actually, this does not relate to your problem.

Comment: I am using simple iEEE overleaf template and there is no bib file denied there.. i created bib file by myself and cited it in main tex file.. there is no IEEEabrv.bib in my folder.. how table of content will help there I didn't get your point

Comment: With a bold guess, you maybe have changed the `\cite` inside your document, so you need a recompilation. That requires a `bibtex` run. But you are on overleaf so it is actually calling `latexmk` so the `bibtex` run will do automatically. There must be something wrong with `\cite`, `\nocite` or other things. Maybe you need to check what contents are between item [8] and [13].

Comment: Sorry, the table of contents thing is in another post about IEEEtran and I confused about them (I've corrected it). `IEEEabrv.bib` does not need to be existent in your folder, and it can be found in LaTeX if you use `cite` package. `IEEEabrv` won't add additional bib entries.

Comment: when i didn't added the ref 13 still there was something and ref was not in order ..

Comment: In this case, well, please also check how you use the bibliography. With your code snippet, it can be deduced that it is `\usepackage{cite}`, (or similarly I use it with `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}`). Also check that other packages like `biblatex` and `natbib` are not used. IEEE Transactions require the basic `cite` package. Otherwise there might be some issues (like the font size problem with `natbib`). The not sorting problem seems to be some additional package configuration. (Or you use `\nocite` or `\nocite{*}` somewhere.) *Here I perceive the order is when the entry first appears*.

Comment: i used the \usepackage{cite} package and i am not using \usepackage[noadjust]{cite}). and  biblatex and I didn't use  \nocite or \nocite{*} somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}`

worked for me.